# OPENROWSET - Como atribuir uma variável no lugar do nome do arquivo para abrir?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Faço esse comando e da certo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\00.000.00.0000\Arquivos\TI\Arquivos\252203408.xlsx;HDR=YES',
    'SELECT * FROM [Rateio$]');
```

Como posso colocar uma variavel no lugar do arquivo '252203408.xlsx' e que eu consiga utilizar o openrowset normalmente?

OBS: Desejo saber isso para fazer essa abertura de diversos arquivos de um diretório.

Comment: Não tem como, exceto se utilizar comando SQL dinâmico.

Answer (score 0):

Use o ***[CONCAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)***; você teria algo tipo:

```
declare @nome_arquivo varchar(255)
select @nome_arquivo = '252203408.xlsx'

SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET( 
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    CONCAT('Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\00.000.00.0000\Arquivos\TI\Arquivos\', @nome_arquivo, ';HDR=YES'),
    'SELECT * FROM [Rateio$]');
```

---

***editado***

Encontrei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13831792/4551469) que parece atender ao que você citou no comentário. Dá uma olhada em como montei a consulta:

```
Declare @nome_arquivo varchar(255)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Set @nome_arquivo = '252203408.xlsx'
Set @sql='SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
               ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
               ''Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\00.000.00.0000\Arquivos\TI\Arquivos\' + @nome_arquivo + ';HDR=YES;'',
               ''SELECT * FROM [Rateio$]'')'

-- Print @sql
Exec(@sql)
```

Comment: não deu certo desta forma, ele da um erro: 'Incorrect syntax near 'CONCAT'.'

Comment: Tentei também fazer um concate antes de tudo: gerando uma variável = SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\00.000.00.000\Arquivos Power BI\TI\Arquivos Base Excel\Rateio\252203408.xlsx;HDR=YESSELECT * FROM [Rateio$]);.. Mas não consigo adicionar dentro dos concats a soma de uma aspa simples.

Comment: @ThaisjtJt dei uma editada baseado em uma pergunta do _SOEN_, veja se resolve o problema.

Comment: Ele da certo, porém precisava deste resultado para atribuir em um cursor. Mas não deixa ler esse exec(@sql)